# How do I configure SimEdit to run locally

Tags: automation

Wanted to document the process of setting up SimEdit to run locally as I know it is a unique process. That way this can be referred to if the other options are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Open Virtual Studio Code:

- Select File > **Open Folder**

  - Select C:/TestOut/*project name*
- From the left tab, expand **NPM SCRIPTS**

  - Select the **course-designers** script

    - Run the script with the **Run** button (play icon)
  - Select the **serve-sims** script

    - Run the script with the **Run** button (play icon)

Open SimEdit

- From the bottom left corner, select **Serving From:**

  - Select **local**